# Need some advice with MondoDB query using aggregate and multiple conditions

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to show only two fields from my collection, the id and the State, with no duplicates, that's why I'm using aggregate with $group, and not find or $project

This is my query

```
db.doc_usa.aggregate([

{$group: {"_id": {State: "$State"} }}

])
```

That query shows

```
{ "_id" : { "State" : "Arizona" } }
```

But i'm searching something like this

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("59e3dbc1944276b685da86d4"), { "State" : "Arizona" } }
```

I'm pretty new with this, so i would thanks complete answers :)

Comment: Presumably the _id is your document's unique identifier, and so every projection of _id and State will be unique.

Comment: As commented already, the `_id` property of ALL MongoDB documents is in "fact" a  **"unique"** property. Including `_id` in the "grouping key" effectively does nothing since they are already unique. Perhaps you actually mean "list of _id values" for each unique `"State"` value?

Comment: I understand now, yeah, an unique _id for a unique "State", i was confused at i was looking for, i think, thanks for your time, i'll keep studying :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query

```
db.doc_usa.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$State"}}])
```

will get you a set of unique states.  Once you pulling the _id from your collection into the grouping, you're going to get every document, because _id is unique.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but i keep some doubts about, for example, the result for that query only shows { "_id" : "Arizona" }, and I'm trying to show something like this { "_id" : ObjectId("59e3dbc1944276b685da86d4"), "State" : "Arizona"}, that's why i was using the $and condition, if I use find for example it shows me the ObjectId but the same State in all rows

Comment: The ObjectId you're looking for is what?  The Id of Arizona?